# Non-Image Polygon fill (e.g., diagonals) in Mapnik?

Tags: symbology, mapnik

Some of the output produced by our team  - primarily on updates for 'legacy' projects - is styled with diagonal line fills (an example appears below).

[image: green stripes]

In mapnik, this can be achieved using

`<PolygonPatternSymbolizer file="[appropriate image]"/>`

The exact same effect is possible "image-free" using `background-image` in CSS3, styled with appropriate gradients.

My preference is for the latter.

My searches indicate that this is not possible in mapnik i.e. it appears that mapnik's PolygonSymbolizer has parameters (fill, fill-opacity, gamma); PolygonPatternSymbolizer takes (file).

I do notice that PolygonSymbolizer.fill 'accepts expressions', as does PolygonPatternSymbolizer.file - so the question is... **can expressions be used to achieve the same effect as the image above**?